# How can assistant professors (without industry experience) become professional engineer in Canada?

Tags: early-career, canada, assistant-professor

I recently asked [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/191906/do-graduate-studies-and-or-postdoc-experience-count-as-work-experience-for-a-p-e/191940#191940) about the acceptance of postdoc years to be counted as professional experience for a professional engineer application (in **Ontario, Canada**). The answer I got (partially) reads as follows:

> Academic experience is not usually considered "professional", although
> I also assume there is a way for very experienced academics to become
> members. In any case, actual assessment is done on a "competency"
> basis where you write a summary of your experience and they assess
> your suitability. I would expect that 24 months of academic experience
> will not give you the professional competency they expect.

I know many assistant professors (without any industrial experience but some years of postdoc) who had become professional engineers around a year after starting their tenure-track positions. So, does one know how this works in Ontario, Canada, if postdoc really is not taken for the required 48 months?

Comment: Is your question related to the requirement that you register as a professional engineer, to be an engineering academic in Canada, e.g. https://uwaterloo.ca/engineering/faculty-and-staff/professional-registration ? When I was on the job market a decade ago and considering north-of-the-border openings, I remember finding that there was a procedure for getting PE accreditation for junior academics; I don’t remember the details. Possibly a senior faculty member was detailed as the “supervisor” to meet the regulation.

Comment: @RLH: Yes, it is. I failed to find such a procedure. I shall be grateful if you share any link regarding details, if possible.

Comment: I can't find anything more than the UWaterloo link in my previous comment. If you already have an established relationship with a university, I would contact the equivalent office to the one named on the UWaterloo page. If you're at an earlier stage in a faculty search, you could ask about the process -- this is something that will come up even for most domestic candidates, so being aware of it and bringing it up doesn't put you at a disadvantage that didn't already exist.

Comment: Found something. Turning it into an answer now

Comment: Actually, I think this should really be answered by someone with actual experience in the Canadian engineering academic sector. This document seems to match what you were looking for, but may be out of date. See 2.4 and 3.1 in particular. https://www.peo.on.ca/sites/default/files/2019-09/RequiredExpForLicensing.pdf